# Having trouble updating the repositories after installing docker

Tags: apt, updates, 20.04, docker

After I installed the docker, when I try to use the `sudo apt update` command, I get the following error:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7EA0A9C34573JCD8
W: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7EA0A9C34573JCD8
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1252216/edit) to show us the entire output of `sudo apt update`. Context matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that you haven't  added official gpg key of docker repository.
Open terminal and execute below command.

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited :

> /etc/apt/sources.list

using the vim editor : `sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list`
And I put a # character at the beginning of the line that included the docker link.

```
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable
```

Comment: That will disable docker repository.